# Gauge transformation as Lie Group

Tags: lie-groups, gauge-theory

How can I prove that the family of Gauge transformations
$$ A_\mu \mapsto A'_\mu = A_\mu +\partial_\mu \phi$$
where $\phi (x)$ is an arbitrary scalar function, is a Lie Group?

Comment: Crossposted from https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/365004/2451

Comment: How can a map from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ be a Lie group?

Comment: The family of Gauge transformations.

Comment: I think you need to be more specific about the space of function that you are choosing your $\phi$ from.

Comment: I choose the $\phi$ that allows me to have a Lie Group. I don't know what it is that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define $ g = \exp (- i \phi )$, you can rewrite this transformation as $A'_\mu = g A_\mu g^{-1} + i (\partial_\mu g ) g^{-1}$ . That is the general form that a gauge field transform for a general gauge group. In particular in your case $ g = \exp (- i \phi )$ is an element of the group U(1). Now if you do the above transformation with $g = g_1$ and then from the result you do a second transformation with $g = g_2$, what you get is exact the above gauge transformation with the element $ g = g_1 g_2$. Therefore, performing two gauge transformations is also a gauge transformation. Moreover, the transformation with $g = 1$ corresponds to the identity transformation and if you perform a transformation with an element $g$ and then another transformation with $g^{-1}$ it is equivalent to the identity transformation with $g=1$. Therefore, this set of transformations satisfy all the properties which defines a group. Alternatively, you can use your equation and perform first a transformation with a parameter $\phi_1$ and then a transformation with a parameter $\phi_2$ and you can see that it is the same as a transformation with $\phi_1 + \phi_2$. Second, you have the transformation with $ \phi = 0$ which corresponds to the identity transformation. And third,  you can do a transformation with $ \phi $ and then a transformation with $ (-\phi) $ and the combination of the two transformations is equivalent to the identity transformation with $ \phi = 0 $.

Comment: Thanks @Photon. You say that (these properties) "defines a group", but do they define a Lie Group?

Comment: A set {a,b,c, ..} with a multiplication $ \cdot $ form a group when: 1) If $a , b \in G$ then $a \cdot b = c \in G$. 2) There exist an identity element $e$ such that $a \cdot e = e \cdot a = a$. 3) For each $a \in G$ there is an element $a^{-1} \in G$ such that $a \cdot a^{-1} = a^{-1} \cdot a = e$. See for instance the book of H. F. Jones on groups.

Comment: I meant: Group $\Longrightarrow $ Lie Group?

Comment: As I mention, these transformations are associated to $ g = \exp (- i \phi ) $ which is a element of the so-called U(1) group, which is a Lie group.

Comment: ok, thanks again @Photon!

Comment: Not quite, the gauge group $\mathcal{G}$ of a gauge theory defined on a principal bundle $P$ with base $M$ and fibre $G$ is the set of smooth automorphisms of $P$. Here $G=U(1)$ and presumably $M=\mathbb{R}^3$ or maybe Minkowski space. In either case $P$ is trivial, hence $P=M\times G$. The gage group is isomorphic to the set of smooth functions from $M$ to the adjoint bundle $P\times_{\mathrm{Ad}} G$. What I wrote is probably not understandable without some background, a good reference is Naber "Topology, Geometry and gauge fields".